# Return empty string into ES6 template string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Im doing the following:

```
return this.innerHTML = `
  <input 
        value = ${this.value ? this.value : ''}
        placeholder=${this.placeholder}
  ></input>
`
```

Now the problem is, that if `this.value` is undefined, undefined as string is set to the inputs value, this is why I try to return an empty string to the inputs value attribute. This doesn't work, I then get `placeholder=${this.placeholder}` as string into the value attribute.

I googled quiet a while now and can't find any answer, is this even possible?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may use `this.value || ''` instead of `this.value ? this.value : ''` for simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't enclosed the value and placeholder in double inverted commas.

```
return this.innerHTML = `
  <input 
        value = "${this.value ? this.value : ''}"
        placeholder="${this.placeholder}"
  ></input>
`
```